# How to query google app engine blobstore by creation date and order the results

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I need to retrieve the latest set of files from GAE blobstore. Currently my code says

```
nDays = 10 #this is set at run time
gqlQuery = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename = :1 ORDER BY creation DESC",<filename>)
cursor = gqlQuery.fetch(nDays)
```

when I iterate and print out the data by calling cursor[i].creation, it doesn't give me the last nDays starting from today. For example, today is August 20. I expect it to give me data from Aug 11 - Aug 20 (I have a file for each day). Instead it gives me data from Aug 13 back a few days.

If i remove the ORDER BY in the gqlquery, it correctly returns all the results (not sorted).
If I make the gqlQuery iterable so that I say something like

```
for filename in gqlQuery:
    print filename.creation
```

it only prints from August 13 back to a few days (about 8 days). I know for a fact there is data up till today. From GAE, I can view the data. Also, the creation date is stamped automatically by Google when the file is uploaded to blobstore.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I may also miss something, but what's the purpose of "filename = :1" in you query?

This ran correctly against my blobstore:

```
gqlQuery = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("ORDER BY creation DESC")
blobs = gqlQuery.fetch(5)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
self.response.out.write("Lasts blobs<br>")
for blob in blobs:
    self.response.out.write(blob.filename + "<br>")
```

Florent

Comment: i have 2 types of files <filename1>, <filename2> so filename = :1 is to select one of the filesets. If I don't specify a filename, then your code will work (I already tried that before and it works). I did some further investigations and it seems like adding the 'ORDER BY' works on the result set before it is filtered by filename instead of working on the result set after applying the filter